# 'Compile Swift source files' build phase - succeeds for arm64 but fails for arm7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I set Build Active Architecture only to 'NO', the build does 'Compile Swift source files' twice. It succeeds for arm64, but fails with a bunch of 'Use of undeclared type' errors for arm7. In the long message, both are identical. Why is this happening?

Edit: This went away and now I'm getting these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Crashlytics", referenced from:
```

and this warning:
    Pods/Fabric/iOS/Fabric.framework/Fabric is not a dylib

I've tried adding Security.framework and other frameworks I found you're supposed to add to 'Link binaries with framework'. It didn't work. I set the architectures to be the same for the Pods and the project. That didn't work either. I'm could try cleaning the build folder and deleting derived data again but I did that already before and it took a long time to index afterwards and didn't work.

Comment: There must be more information in the error log. Which type is undeclared? Where (do you think) is the type defined? Are 3rd-party frameworks (pods, ...) used?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I'm using Cocoapods and the errors are related to these Pods: Alamofire, Charts (danielgindi) and ObjectMapper - edit: FacebookLogin too

Comment: @MartinR This went away and I'm getting new errors in the linking phase. Question edited.